# Sheet.hide() sometimes works sometimes not

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

this is my final script

```
function archive2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName('Lista');      // name of source sheet
  var sourceRange = source.getRange('A1:B');    // range to copy
  var destination1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); // name of log sheet
  var lastRow = destination1.getLastRow();
  sourceRange.copyTo(destination1.getRange(5000 + 1, 1),{contentsOnly:true});
  var source = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');      // name of source sheet
  var sourceRange = source.getRange('H1:I5000');    // range to copy
  var destination2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3'); // name of log sheet
  var lastRow = destination2.getLastRow();
  destination2.getRange('A1:B').activate();
  destination2.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  var source = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');      // name of source sheet
  var sourceRange = source.getRange('H1:I5000');    // range to copy
  var destination3 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3'); // name of log sheet
  sourceRange.copyTo(destination3.getRange(1 + 1, 1),{contentsOnly:true});
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');      // name of source sheet
  var sourceRange = source.getRange('A1:B5000');    // range to copy
  var destination4 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); // name of log sheet
  var lastRow = destination4.getLastRow();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:B').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  sourceRange.copyTo(destination4.getRange('A:B'),{contentsOnly:true});
  var hide1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  hide1.hideSheet();
  var hide2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  hide2.hideSheet();
}
```

Basically it makes a static copy of some data that I need to sum later. This part works fine.

What isn't working are the last lines, basically I want to hide Sheet2 and Sheet3, which are helper sheets to make the calcs.

The best way would be to make all the calcs without unhide those sheets but I wasn't able to find a solution (so if someone know what I've to change to perform it, would be great), so I'm searching a way to at least hide them after the script run.

With these lines, sometimes they are both hide, sometime just 1 of them (randomly between sheet2 and sheet3, I guess it have something to do with "active", and so I've tried to active both in sequence but still doesn't work).

Could you help me to hide both everytime (or make it works without unhide anything at all) without failures? Thanks

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GREsQNrDAaLqOROwAixajK6tpTRGOhqGHo0kfyyyuGw/edit#gid=0

Comment: I'd guess that it's not getting that far for some other reason because the hides look ok to me.  Try simplifying the code or remove some stuff and see what it takes to make it more reliable.  Also I wouldn't use this kind of notation in ranges: `'A:B'`  it often leaves a huge number of nulls at the bottom of the sheet.  I stick to `(row,column,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn)` it's a lot less problematic.

Comment: I made a copy of your spreadsheet with the bound script and ran the `archive2` function from the script editor and it's working copying values to Sheet2 and Sheet3 and then hides both. Is there an extra step to reproduce this issue?